# Turn Html table row into two floating divs with css

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-table

I am trying to transfer a table into a set of floating divs and I can't seem to get it. How can I make .div1 and .div2 behave like .td1 and .td2?

**UPDATED (also replaced prior icon with image to show more clearly the issue.**

[Fiddle showing how it SHOULD work](http://jsfiddle.net/j7f7jag1/)

table (before)

```
<table>
```

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60">
</td>
<td class="td2"  style="padding-left: 8px">
  <h4>
    <strong>
      Title 
    </strong>
   </h4>
      <span>
            Here is come placeholder Text
      </span>

</td>
```

[Fiddle showing how it doesn't work with divs](http://jsfiddle.net/n69aro2x/) 

divs (after?  Not working)

```
<div class="div_wrapper" style="display:inline-block">
<div  class="div1" style="width: 62px; vertical-align: top; padding-top:5px">

<img src="http://placehold.it/60x60">
</div>
<div class="div2" style="padding-left: 8px">
  <h4>
    <strong>
      Title 
    </strong>
   </h4>
      <span>
            Here is come placeholder Text
      </span>

</div>
```

Comment: what is not working.?

Comment: I've updated the code to show you.  div1 and div2 should line up horizontally like td1 and td2.  I've made two fiddles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you can use float.

http://jsfiddle.net/n69aro2x/1/

Here is the code :-

```
<div class="div_wrapper" style="display:inline-block">
    <div  class="div1" style="width: 62px; vertical-align: top; padding-top:5px; float:left">

    <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60">
    </div>
    <div class="div2" style="padding-left: 8px; float:left;">
      <h4>
        <strong>
          Title 
        </strong>
       </h4>
          <span>
                Here is come placeholder Text
          </span>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin to align text :-

```
<div class="form-group" style="display:inline-block">
    <div  class="div1" style="width: 33px; vertical-align: top; padding-top:5px">

    <i class="fa fa-cog" style="font-size: 36px"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="div2" style="padding-left: 8px">
      <h4>
        <strong style="margin-left:30px;">
          Title 
        </strong>
       </h4>
        <br/>
          <span style="margin-left:30px;">
                Here is come placeholder Text
          </span>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not text alignment that is the problem.  I've updated my question with two fiddles showing the issues.

Answer (score 0):

hi the below is given the using table and using div's both demo code

here is the demo code using table

[Dmo code using table](https://jsfiddle.net/9qch258y/)

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="td1" width= "33" style="vertical-align: top; padding-top:5px">

    <i class="fa fa-cog " style="font-size: 36px"></i>
    </td>
    <td class="td2"  style="padding-left: 8px">
      <h4>
        <strong>
          Title 
        </strong>
       </h4>
        <br/>
          <span>
                Here is come placeholder Text
          </span>

    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

---

here is the demo code made using div's

[Demo code made using div's](https://jsfiddle.net/kpu5ohpp/)

```html
<div class="form-group" style="display:inline-block">
    <div  class="div1" style="width: 33px; vertical-align: top; padding-top:13px">

    <i class="fa fa-cog" style="font-size: 36px"></i>
    </div>
<div class="table_wrapper_div">
    <div class="div2" style="padding-left: 53px;">
        <h4><strong>Title</strong></h4><br/>
        <span>Here is come placeholder Text</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere as i understand your question i tried this way please check out

Comment: what does your class "table_wrapper_div" do?

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere   Nothing i just wrapped the your divs